# Diagnostics of the IGBT transistors in the three phase inverter

Tags: power-electronics, inverter, measurement, multimeter, igbt

Let's say I have three phase voltage source inverter i.e. following circuit

[image]

I have a suspicion that one or more IGBTs are damaged. To confirm this hypothesis I have decided to use multimeter in ohmmeter setting and I have measured the resistance between the collector and emitor terminals of the individual IGBTs. I have measured resistances between:

- terminal *30,31,32* and terminal *2* for IGBT in upper row on the left
- terminal *30,31,32* and terminal *6* for IGBT in upper row in the middle
- terminal *30,31,32* and terminal *10* for IGBT in upper row on the right
- terminal *27,28,29* and terminal *4* for IGBT in lower row on the left
- terminal *24,25,26* and terminal *8* for IGBT in lower row in the middle
- terminal *21,22,23* and terminal *12* for IGBT in lower row on the right

My multimeter displayed follwoing values of the resistance

- OL
- \$22.95\,\mathrm{k}\Omega\$
- \$23\,\mathrm{k}\Omega\$
- \$7\,\mathrm{M}\Omega\$
- \$5.7\,\mathrm{M}\Omega\$
- \$4.8\,\mathrm{M}\Omega\$

Does it mean that all of the transistors are ok (because none of the measurements displayed \$0\,\Omega\$ or some value close to that) or is there any mistake in my measurement (I expected that all the measurements should be OL in case all of the transistors are ok)?

**EDIT**:

I have done another measurement with multimeter configured in diode test mode and I have measured voltage drop between

- terminal *2* (positive probe) and terminal *30,31,32* (negative probe) for IGBT in upper row on the left
- terminal *6* (positive probe) and terminal *30,31,32* (negative probe) for IGBT in upper row in the middle
- terminal *10* (positive probe) and terminal *30,31,32* (negative probe) for IGBT in upper row on the right
- terminal *4* (positive probe) and terminal *27,28,29* (negative probe) for IGBT in lower row on the left
- terminal *8* (positive probe) and terminal *24,25,26* (negative probe) for IGBT in lower row in the middle
- terminal *12* (positive probe) and terminal *21,22,23* (negative probe) for IGBT in lower row on the right

My multimeter displayed follwoing values of the voltage drops

- \$0.03\,\mathrm{V}\$
- \$0.374\,\mathrm{V}\$
- \$0.374\,\mathrm{V}\$
- \$0.374\,\mathrm{V}\$
- \$0.374\,\mathrm{V}\$
- \$0.000\,\mathrm{V}\$

Comment: I find resistance measurement dubious when it comes to semiconductors. Set your multimeter to diode test mode and fill in the values for that too in the table above. Please note that it’s polarity sensitive.

Comment: @winny thank you for your reaction. I have just attempted to do the measurement you have suggested. Please see the edit in my question.

Comment: Thanks. I can’t correlate which one is which but 0 V = shorted and 0.37 V = body diode a d probably fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is wrong with your upper left and lower right IGBTs; both of them appear to show no antiparallel diode. I'm not sure why they don't show low impedance in the opposite direction, though. When you say you measured the resistances between two nodes, do you mean you put the positive probe on the first and negative on the second? It does matter with semiconductor devices.

Another test that's good to make is the gate to emitter and gate to collector impedance--if it's anything less than hundreds of MΩ, something is probably wrong. If it's less than a kΩ, something is definitely wrong.

Comment: I would say _probably_ something is wrong. Gate drive and any CE snubbers may put you below 100 Mohm with nothing being wrong. The schematic above is just a simplification.

Comment: Okay, fair--I should clarify that a little.

Comment: Much better! :-)